# Locating file in the hard disk using Java just like the os.walk in python

Tags: java, python

I am pretty new in Java (Learning about 2 weeks)
I am trying to find the cleanest way to do do a global file search in java.
Is there any possibility to use a similar function to the os.walk in python?
When using the os.walk I just require to put the base directory that the source should start from.

I found the Files.walk() function but I cannot the correct syntax to provide it a name of file to return.

My main purpose is to send a file name from the main function to the search function and receive the absolute patch for this file.
Can someone assist with that?

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, `Files.walk` is correct method to iterate through all the files in the directory. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) the javadoc for it, this is what it says:

> Return a Stream that is lazily populated with Path by walking the file
>   tree rooted at a given starting file.

All you need to do is wrap this method call into another method (that accepts a path and a search string) and return list of matching files, e.g.:

```
public List<String> search(String path, String searchString) throws Exception{
    Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(path));
    try{
        List<String> files = paths
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString))
                .map(p -> p.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return files;
    }finally{
        if(null != paths){
            paths.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This example only returns files, if you want it to return directories as well, then you can use `Files.isDirectory` method with an `OR` condition. Here's the javadoc for [isDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-).